# Merge 2 different line charts to have same x and y axis in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, linechart, power-bi-report-server

I’m new to power BI. I need to create a line chart with total number of postings by year by employers.
USER’s data:
[user's posting count by year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmhHk.png)

Other companies
[other companies posting count by year based on user selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP3lq.png)

I need to combine these two charts together **with same y axis**
[final report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvnrH.png)

If the user of these reports is company A he is represented by the yellow line. And it should appear by default. Other lines must appear as the user selects more employers. The dropdown on the right should not have “company A” listed for selection or deselection.

Comment: Is 'Company A' for all users the same, or is there a column which holds the company for each user? In other words: how do you know which company belongs to the user?

Comment: No the company name is assigned based on user's credentials.